# How does Zap work in "Chameleon the game"?

Tags: untagged

When reading through the rules to "Chameleon the game" there is an action called zap which sends the opposing players piece to the start. I read the rules but cannot quite work out the mechanics of the steps.

The rules indicate the dice are used for Zapping but do not clearly indicate how.

**Front of the box**

[image: Front of the box]

**Back of the box**
[image]

**Board and pieces**
[image: Board and pieces]

**Rulebook**
[image: Rulebook]

Comment: This is a little tricky. I originally assumed this question was about the word-based bluffing game by Rikki Tahta, call ["The Chameleon"](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/227072/chameleon). But that game doesn't have opposing pieces, or a zap action. OP, can you pinpoint which game you mean, potentially listed in [this BGG search](https://boardgamegeek.com/geeksearch.php?action=search&q=chameleon&objecttype=boardgame)?

Comment: On looking through possibilities, I'm guessing it's most likely [this game](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/119431/chameleon). I'll see if there's any information on how the zap rule works.

Comment: @ConMan it has the same description but a different looking board.  Would it help if I added some photos of the game.

Comment: Yes it would help. As it stands there is confusion over which game you are referring to so it will be impossible to get you an answer.

Comment: @JoeW I've added the images of the game.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this version of ***Chameleon the Game*** is an English reprint of a French game called ***Le Chameleon***.
Unfortunately the Australian company that printed this game, and the original French company both seem to have gone defunct.

Luckily we have part of the French rules, and a semi-established terminology for "*Zapped*";
Zapping is the act of moving by exact roll onto a space occupied by an opposing piece, and thereby removing them from the game-board, and placing them into their original starting position.

What's still unclear though, is if you are able to "*Zap*" a piece using the optional move distance allowed when rolling a 6 (or Chameleon).